# Why isn't return bound to newline-and-indent by default on emacs

Tags: emacs, newline, default

I have tried emacs on and off for a while now and every time I start emacs, I go through the same routine. Customizing. The first one is binding return to newline-and-indent. (g)Vim does this by default. Showing matching parenthesis is also done by default on (g)Vim. It is grea that I can customize emacs to my heart's content but why doesn't emacs have nice and easy defaults? For reference, I am now using Emacs 23 on a RHEL5 box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably because RMS didn't want it, that and because changing long-standing defaults is just an issue of politics.  Like vi, Emacs has a hard-core following and basic changes like these are minefields.

Note: if you saved your customizations, then you wouldn't have to re-do them every time...

Comment: I did save those settings in my .emacs file. Just that I kept losing it whenever I switched machines. Of course, now it is online in a source control repository, so it should be easy to retrieve.

Answer (score 2):

To have those nice and easy defaults, install [Emacs Starter Kit](http://emacsblog.org/2008/12/05/emacs-starter-kit/). It enables by default a bunch of useful and convenient features make even the advanced Emacs users more productive.

Otherwise, [as TJ pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458181/why-isnt-return-bound-to-newline-and-indent-by-default-on-emacs/1458238#1458238), Emacs Customization Mode (type `M-x customize`) allows you to save permanently any of the settings. You can even store them in a separate file from your dotemacs―`(setq custom-file "~/.emacs-custom.el")`―so you can use it in every computer you work on.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to Emacs Starter Kit. I'll try it out.

Answer (score 2):

The title of your question doesn't really reflect what your question is (and has been answered by Trey and Torok), but I'll tell you why I like it being bound to just newline: useless whitespace.  Say you are nested inside a conditional in a function etc. and hit return a couple times to leave a blank line.  The blank line now has a bunch of space chars on it.  Yes, you can (and I do) remove trailing whitespace before saving, but I also have visual whitespace mode on and I can see it there taunting me.

Comment: That's kind of annoying. In that case, Vim would remove the unneeded indent spaces when you press Enter the second time if you haven't typed anything else on the line.

Comment: Sure, you could write some simple elisp to do that in Emacs, but what about when you add a blank line then navigate away, or save the file, or etc.

Comment: Vim also removes the unneeded indent spaces when leaving insert mode. I don't intend this to degenerate into an emacs-vim war, so I'll just leave it at that.